# How to override task decorator in Airflow for testing?

Tags: python, airflow

I am using a `@task.external_python` decorator that points to a custom `venv` with some additional dependencies.

I want to be able to write an integration tests where I mock certain API's `requests-mock` and have entire DAG run end to end. That means that my pytest and dag should run in the same process.

I figured that I can make a custom task decorator that switches between `external_python` and `python` depending on the environment. When I run the code in pytest it will use `python` which will technically run the code in the same `pytest` process with configured mocks. My idea is obviously monkey patching that actually leaks in a production code – which I am aint a fan of.

I have a few questions:

- is there a way to redefine task operator on the fly in tests?
- if not, how do I write a custom task decorator without building a provider?
- Or maybe there is a better way to provide mocks for API's in tasks?

I do have a lot of tests for individual tasks, however, I still want to test dags on certain subsets of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow, for anyone wondering how to test entire dags in pytest, here is the solution.

First you need to load a DagBag – I do it as a fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def airflow_dags(airflow_home, monkeypatch):
    # region replace @task.external_python with local python context in which tests are running
    def python_task_replacement(*args, **kwargs):
        return task_decorator_factory(
            decorated_operator_class=_PythonDecoratedOperator,
        )

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        "airflow.decorators.task.external_python", python_task_replacement
    )
    # endregion

    return path.abspath(path.join(airflow_home, "dags"))

@pytest.fixture()
def airflow_dagbag(airflow_dags):
    return DagBag(include_examples=False, dag_folder=airflow_dags)
```

Then in your lovely tests, you can load your dags, prepare all mocks for network, etc and enjoy the integration test for the entire dag.

```py
@pytest.mark.integration
@requests_mock.Mocker(kw="mock")
def test_rp_example(
    airflow_dagbag, sl_client_group, assets_path, monkeypatch, **kwargs
):
    # Ensure we can load the dag itself
    dag = airflow_dagbag.get_dag(dag_id="realpage-inventory-api")

    assert airflow_dagbag.import_errors == {}
    assert dag is not None
    assert len(dag.tasks) > 0

    # Run dag and validate results
    dag.clear()

    # In order to run the dag, we need to somehow point the configured venv to the current poetry venv that we're
    # running these tests from
    dag_run = dag.test()

    assert dag_run.get_state() == DagRunState.SUCCESS
```